# How to get all the child records from different tables based on given parent ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 different tables:

```
select * from System;
select * from Set;
select * from Item;
select * from Versions;
```

Now for each system Id there will be **n no.of Sets**, and for each set there will be **n no. of Items** and for **each item** there will be **n no.of Versions**.

Each system has:

- n no of set
- each Set has

  - n no of Items
  - each Item has

    - n no of Versions

When I have a specific `SystemId`, I want to retrieve all the records from `Set` and `Items` of each set and `Versions` of each item in a single stored procedure and insert those records into respective tables again with different Id's.

Comment: Search for `INNER JOIN` or `IN` or `EXISTS`

Comment: what do you mean by `insert those records in respective tables again with different Id's.`? Can you give example

Comment: Once i retrive records of all childs then i have insert them again in those tables with different System Id reference.

Answer (score 0):

With few efforts you could have found that, I suggest you to research for a while before asking questions.
I you want to change system id, then it won't affect other tables if you have normalized them properly, my suggestion is to normalize them first
After normalizing them you won't need complex logic for understanding.
 As per my understanding INNER JOIN would work best for you.

```
@SysID int

SELECT 
* 
FROM System S1,
INNER JOIN
SET S2,
on S1.SystemID = S2.SystemID
INNER JOIN
ITEMS S3
on S2.SetID = S3.SetID
INNER JOIN
VERSIONS S4
on S3.ItemID = S4.ItemID
WHERE S1.SystemID = @SysID
```

The fields Containing ID are primary key for tables with the same name followed by "ID" and Foreign Key when referenced through other tables.

Let me know if questions
Thankyou